# Carbon cycle in a sulphur-based biochemistry

Tags: internal-consistency, atmosphere, chemistry, biochemistry

I'm designing a world with advanced life forms that use a sulphur-based biochemistry (see [this link](https://expansion.world/destination) for context). I would like to create a carbon cycle analogous to Earth, where:

- Photosynthesis transforms carbon dioxide (CO<sub>2</sub>) and water (H<sub>2</sub>O) into glucose (C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>12</sub>O<sub>6</sub>) and oxygen (O<sub>2</sub>).
- Cellular respiration consumes O<sub>2</sub> and releases CO<sub>2</sub> + H<sub>2</sub>O, maintaining equilibrium.

In my world, I would like:

- Photosynthesis to take methane (CH<sub>4</sub>) and sulphuric acid (H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>) to produce sulphur dioxide (SO<sub>2</sub>) and a hydrocarbon that performs the same role as glucose (let's call it substance X).
- Cellular respiration to consume SO<sub>2</sub> and release CH4 + H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>, again maintaining equilibrium.
- Substance X would therefore need to have a molecular formula with 1×C, 6×H, 2×O (or a multiple in proportion,
  e.g., 2×C, 12×H, 4×O).
- No oxygen (O<sub>2</sub>) in the atmosphere.
- No production of water in the photosynthetic reaction.

The ideal solution would be a hydrocarbon that actually exists, with a molecular formula using the atoms mentioned above. If that's not possible, what if:

- Sulphur trioxide (SO<sub>3</sub>) is used instead of SO<sub>2</sub>?
- A third, nitrogen-based gas is added (such as ammonia or nitric acid) such that photosynthesis takes CH<sub>4</sub>, H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>, third gas; and respiration takes SO<sub>2</sub> to release CH<sub>4</sub>, H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub> and the third gas.

Comment: Hi Ally, welcome to Worldbuilding! May I suggest that your question might be better worded as such? Perhaps something like: "How might photosynthesis function in a sulphur-based biochemistry?"

Comment: What wrong with $6\mathrm{CH}_4 + 6\mathrm{H}_2\mathrm{SO}_4 \leftrightarrow \mathrm{C}_6\mathrm{H}_{12}\mathrm{O}_6 \cdot 6\mathrm{H}_2\mathrm{O} + 6\mathrm{SO}_2$?

Comment: @AlexP Which direction will that reaction prefer to go in the context of earth-like conditions?

Comment: If people disagree with me, change it back, but I added [chemistry] to the tag mix.  Because this is about both chemistry in life forms (for which [biochemistry] is perfect) and chemistry of the atmosphere and other non-living things.  Oh and [atmosphere].

Comment: Thanks @ArkensteinXII. I'm happy to rename the post to make it clearer - but my question is actually not about photosynthesis. I'm interested in the entire cycle - autotroph organisms converting A to B, where heterotrophs then convert B back to A, keeping a balance. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: @AlexP good point - I forgot to add that I would prefer the reaction not to produce water. The planet's oceans are composed of sulphuric acid; I assume water would react with it. I edited the question to add that clarification.

Comment: @AllyEnfield Water does indeed react with sulphuric acid in an endothermic reaction. It is possible that your organisms could utilise that energy perhaps? It is going to be very difficult to exclude water from a planetary environment in that it periodically falls from space, and is produced by a variety of geological processes.

Comment: Thanks @ArkensteinXII. I'll need to consider water then. Is there a realistic way that organisms could use the reaction's energy? I thought heat would always be lost.

Comment: @AllyEnfield The first thing that comes to mind is that, much like cold-blooded organisms of Earth, they could use it simple to maintain body temperature? There are undoubtedly mechanisms by which a lifeform could capture that energy, even if only in part.

Comment: Bril, good ideas there @ArkensteinXII, thank you. Back to the drawing board :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have invented [sulfate reducing microorganisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfate-reducing_microorganisms)

> Sulfate-reducing microorganisms (SRM) or sulfate-reducing prokaryotes
>   (SRP) are a group composed of sulfate-reducing bacteria (SRB) and
>   sulfate-reducing archaea (SRA), both of which can perform anaerobic
>   respiration utilizing sulfate (SO42–) as terminal electron acceptor,
>   reducing it to hydrogen sulfide (H2S). Therefore, these sulfidogenic
>   microrganisms "breathe" sulfate rather than molecular oxygen (O2),
>   which is the terminal electron acceptor reduced to water (H2O) in
>   aerobic respiration....In terms of electron donor, this group contains
>   both organotrophs and lithotrophs. The organotrophs oxidize organic
>   compounds, such as carbohydrates, organic acids (e.g., formate,
>   lactate, acetate, propionate, and butyrate), alcohols (methanol and
>   ethanol), aliphatic hydrocarbons (including methane), and aromatic
>   hydrocarbons (benzene, toluene, ethylbenzene, and xylene)

You do not need photosynthesis because there is enough power in sulfate to reduce methane.  These creatures are the heterotrophs in your world (and ours), the equivalent of animals up in the oxic world.

You can model your plants on [purple sulfur bacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_sulfur_bacteria).  They do photosynthesis.  Like plants they kick out oxidized stuff as waste; oxygen for plants, sulfuric acid for the PSBs.

> The purple sulfur bacteria (PSB) are part of a group of Proteobacteria
>   capable of photosynthesis, collectively referred to as purple
>   bacteria... Unlike plants, algae, and cyanobacteria, purple sulfur
>   bacteria do not use water as their reducing agent, and therefore do
>   not produce oxygen. Instead, they can use sulfur in the form of
>   sulfide, or thiosulfate.. The sulfur is oxidized to produce granules
>   of elemental sulfur. This, in turn, may be oxidized to form sulfuric
>   acid.

If you think that kind of thing is cool, you are right.  Read up.  It is amazing and it is real.

Comment: This is a great answer, +1; just note for the querent that this answer reverses the use of the sulphate group, using it for respiration (playing the role of oxygen).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @Willk. This allows me to play with H2S and SO4 as alternatives I hadn't considered before. Having read the article I noticed SR* and PSB reactions produce water as a final byproduct, which wouldn't work in the equation that I'm looking for.